# Why javascript function don't work for onclick event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a event to verify if 2 input values are equals, but the javascript function dont works

I want to compare the valus of 2 text input box in realtime, like webforms, when the user type into the text box, the web says if the values match or not

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h2 id="resultado">Resultado</h2> 
        <div >
            <label id="passwordlabel"  for="password1">Contraseña</label>
            <input name="password" type="text" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Contraseña no válida.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div >
              <label for="password2">Confirme Contraseña</label>
              <input name="password2" type="password"  id="password2" onclick="pass()" placeholder="Repita contraseña"  required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Las contraseñas deben ser iguales.
              </div>
          </div>

    <script src="js/password-validation.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the JS file

```
function pass() {
'use strict'


result=document.getElementById("resultado");
result.innerHTML = "el java script sirve";

    var inputPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var inputPassword2 = document.getElementById('password2').value;

      if ( inputPassword != inputPassword2) {
        
        result.innerHTML = "values don't match";
      }
      else{
        result.innerHTML = "values match";
      }
   })
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "dont works"? What have you tried to check **why** this does not work? And what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: The script simply dont do nothing, i tried using a addEventListainer but nothing happens , simply i dont know why dont works

Comment: You have to call the function.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: `Onclick` may only get called if the user clicks to focus on the field, or afterward, if at all. I would try `onChange` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- At the end of your function you have an unnecessary parentheses `)`

2- If you use `use strict` you need to declare your variables: `var result = ...`

3- Probably is conceptually wrong to check the two fields with an `onclick` on textbox, but this is not a formal error.

```js
function pass() {
  'use strict'


  var result = document.getElementById("resultado");
  result.innerHTML = "el java script sirve";

  var inputPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var inputPassword2 = document.getElementById('password2').value;

  if (inputPassword != inputPassword2) {

    result.innerHTML = "values don't match";
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "values match";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h2 id="resultado">Resultado</h2> 
        <div >
            <label id="passwordlabel"  for="password1">Contraseña</label>
            <input name="password" type="text" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Contraseña no válida.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div >
              <label for="password2">Confirme Contraseña</label>
              <input name="password2" type="password"  id="password2" onclick="pass()" placeholder="Repita contraseña"  required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Las contraseñas deben ser iguales.
              </div>
          </div>

    <script src="js/password-validation.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, the code works now, but, how i can improve it? what is the most formal way to check these values, i want now check the match while the value is typing, using on-change event or using jquery?

Comment: @jimmy714 Generally these forms work with a button (the classic password change form) but it depends on how you want it. `onchange` works when you leave the field, impractical? perhaps better with `keyup`, with each key pressed. Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qz3vb1ca/). If you think my answer is correct remember to mark it, thanks.